# How to set cursor off screen?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a website for a kiosk. I've got 3 divs on one page, everytime when a div is clicked, next div shows up using a photoslide, and the previous div hides away.

My problem is that when the welcome screen (first div) is showing (the whole page/div is an a tag), the status bar down the bottom shows the linking address all the time. I posted another post, people told me it is not possible to hide the status bar.

So my question is how do I set the cursor to be off screen/off set, so the status bar only shows when a visitor is interacting with the screen.

Can I set the cursor offset using javascript, html/css or php? Any code/suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is my html page below or see http://jsfiddle.net/EXfnN/8/

```
 <div id="item1" class="item">


        <div class="content">


            <a href="#item2" class="panel">

            <video id="my_Video" width="100%" height="100%" preload="auto" autoplay loop>xxxxxx
            </video>

            </a>

        </div>
       </div>



      <div id="item2" class="item">

       <div class="content">    
          <div id="back">

          <ul id="awesome-menu">

            <li>  

                   <a href="#item3"  onclick="abcSubmit()" id="abc" class="panel">ABC</a>

            </li>   

            <li>

              <a href="#item3" onclick="nationalSubmit()" id="national" class="panel">National</a>


            </li>   

            <li>

                   <a href="#item3" onclick="otherSubmit()" id="other" class="panel">Other</a>

            </li>       

          </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
   </div>

       <div id="item3" class="item">

            <div class="content">
                 <a href="#item1" class="panel"><img src="images/thankyou.jpg" alt="Thank you" /></a></div>
       </div>
```

Comment: It looks like that the kiosk is not properly configured. Contact the kiosk vendor about the configuration option to hide the status bar.

Comment: Isn't `element.blur()` sufficient?

Comment: Hi Hakre, what do you mean by kiosk configuration? Where can I do it? We are using firefox kiosk mode on a pc machine and it is connected to a big tv screen. Is there anywhere we can hide the status bar? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Marat, I'm fairly new to this field, can you explain a bit more on thie element/blur() function, how can I use it? Thank you.

Comment: `element.blur()` method removes focus from subject element if it's focused currently. If link has no focus, its URL should not be shown in browser's status bar.

Comment: @SamIAm: Check the [*R-kiosk* Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/). It should suit your needs. If not it leaves some pointers. Firefox can be configured inside out, some pointers: [Firefox Lockdown](http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/linuxkiosk/webterm02.htm) (even if little outdated it shows which multiple things exist to tailor Firefox. Some setting names might have changed and some config files moved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that if you're using JavaScript for this, that you don't need ANCHOR tags because you've already negated the need for them.

I'd suggest changing to adding click events to the div tags and storing additional application data on "data-" attributes and reading those with JavaScript instead.

This workaround eliminates a few problems like the one above.

Comment: Hi My Stream, i have edited my code above. Is it possible for you to give me some example code to work on. I tried to use a and onclick before, but everytime i clicked on the first div, it shows the second div in another window. Any suggestion would be great. Thanks.

Comment: IF the div shows in another window- you might need to use `return false;` in your onclick functions so that the code can run without letting the browser open the link defined by the href attribute.  Can you post your JavaScript code on jsfiddle so we can look at your situation more closely?

Comment: Hi Mystream, thanks for the follow up. Here is the structure of my page, http://jsfiddle.net/EXfnN/8/  As you can image, the first page will be in a kiosk mode, since it is an a tag, the status bar will always show down the bottom, as requested I have to somehow make it disappear, that's why locate the cursor off screen came to my mind. Thank you.

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/EXfnN/10/ might get you going (doesn't really work in jsFiddle land, due to the missing resources).

Comment: @BlairMcMillan - same approach - nice

Comment: @MyStream and BlairMcMillan, thanks very much for the code, it fixed my first page's problem, great help! A little further question, is there anyway I can keep my a tag in the li on the second div/page? As there are buttons as a list on that page, I need to set the buttons to active when the button is clicked. How can I get around that using your code? Thanks again:)

Comment: You can use the same approach on all elements, avoiding the need for anchor tags, I'd suggest you use a span tag, however, since it gets quite hacky, I'd suggest asking the kiosk vendor to see if there's a way to remove the url from showing up to start with.

Answer (score 1):

you could make the first element a div only (without the a tag) catch the onclick event and then redirect via javascript (or do whatever action the a tag has)?

Comment: Hi Stratton, the first div is actually a html5 video which is an a tag, and when you click anywhere on the video, the second div will slide to show. I'm not so sure how to use the onclick event and redirect via javascript you mentioned, is it possible for you to give me more details on it/some code? I tried a tag and onclick, everytime when the a tag is click a new window shows up which is not going to work for this kiosk case, I need it to stay on one page. Any suggestions? Thanks very much.