# How to set the cursor position on the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way I can set the cursor position off the screen/webpage or on top/bottom of the page when a page is load? If so how can I target it, maybe using javascript, jquery or php? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you're trying to accomplish? If you're trying to set an action for a 'hover' event, you can simply accomplish that by faking the action in the backend .There should never be any reason to physically require the mouse to be located somewhere on page load for something to happen - because you can create that effect of whatever the 'mouse position' is triggering.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, the reason I want to move the mouse pointer off screen is because the page I'm creating is an a tag page, so people click anywhere next page will show. I don't want people to see the status bar address when they open the page until they move the mouse and interact with the page, that's why moving cursor off the screen came to my mind. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I would use an overlay with a 100% transparent background. this will disallow anyone from clicking through to under the element, but will show all of the data beneath it. Then I would call the jquery .mousemove function, and remove the layover from the DOM.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, that sounds very good. Sorry I'm fairly new to the field. Is there any links/code/tutorials I can check out to learn this method please? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I'll put my response in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This response is based on the user having the need to avoid interacting with the page on load. It was not phrased correctly at first.**

First, we'll need to create the layover. For this, we're going to use an ID of 'pageLayover'.

our CSS:

```
#pageLayover{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:transparent;
  z-index:9000;
  display:block;
}
```

Then our jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $("body").append('<div id="pageLayover"></div>');
  $(document).mousemove(function(){ //capture mouse movement event
    $("#pageLayover").remove(); // remove our layover from the DOM
  });
});
```

That's the basics. You can tweak with it from there. Several users are constantly using their mouse so you may want to delay the use of the function until after a few seconds of the page load.

Good luck.

**Editing to provide better Visibility to Solution**

I agree with MyStream here, This is definitely not a finite solution. There's tweaking to be done, as I noted in the comment.

If you want this to also be a click function, you simply need to make it a click function.

```
$("#myClickElement").live('click', function(){
  $("body").append('<div id="pageLayover"></div>');
});
```

will append the pagelayover. If you want to move the scope of the remove to a click, you could use the normalized mousedown function, such as ->

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
  if(event.which == 1){ $("#pageLayover").remove(); 
});
```

Comment: thanks for the code, I have added to my code on http://jsfiddle.net/EXfnN/17/ so it is for the first page, but it's not working. Would you be able to have a look and see if I've done something wrong? I appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the jsFiddle. Check it now. the code needs to be at the top and I changed the background to be black so you can see that the layover does indeed work. What you need to understand is that the instant you move your mouse, the layover will be removed from the DOM. As I said earlier, if you want to delay that effect, you can set a timeout, or monitor the distance the mouse travels, etc.

Comment: Also I should note that you do not need to call $(function(){ from within a $(function(). $(function(){ literally translates to the jQuery format of $(document).ready(function(), which is translated from the regular JS, which is window.onload = function(){ }.

Comment: this might not work 100% if the user just clicks without moving - such as if the 'next' button appears in the same place on 2 consecutive 'slides' - but a good start to a solution?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I can see the light from your code after days of trying, thanks. One more questions please, is there anyway I make your function work again when the photoslide page comes back to the first div/page again, please see http://jsfiddle.net/EXfnN/19/ what I mean is when the last thank you page/div shows for 3 secs, it will auto go back to the first page/div shows again, how can I make your function work again? Thank you!!

Comment: @MyStream and Ohgodwhy, it is definitely a good start. Is this possible to make this a click and a mouse move function? Can I make this function work again after the third div/page and when first div shows again? Thank you! PS I don't want to refresh the page due to memory space.

Comment: Ohgodwhy can you add that to your answer - @SamIAm, I think you should specify a bit more of the interactivity with an edit to your questino so that Ohgodwhy can update to match it as closely as possible next time - otherwise the comments may exceed utility.

Comment: Thanks Ohgodwhy and Mystream, as all my divs are on a page, I've got one last question: is it possible to make this function work again when it comes back to the first page/div after you viewed the third thank you page? At the moment the function only works when the page first load. (I can't use the reload function due to the memory space.) It would be great if you could update http://jsfiddle.net/EXfnN/20/ Thanks very much for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

There's no way of setting the mouse position in Javascript. It envolves a serious security issue.
Imagine how chaotic it would be if any web site could take control over your mouse.

Comment: Hi Deantoni, thanks for your reply. So is there any way I can set where the cursor is when a page is load, then people can move it by mouse? Thanks.

Comment: No - but you can possibly set the focus - not position - to be within a particular form field or element on the page.

Comment: As @MyStream said, you can "guide" the user by focusing a given element.

Comment: @MyStream and Deantoni, the reason I want to move the mouse pointer off screen is because the page I'm creating is an a tag page, so people click anywhere next page will show. I don't want people to see the status bar address when they open the page until they move the mouse and interact with the page. Can focus do that? Thanks.

Comment: No, but perhaps blur can or setting focus to a different element, such as a hidden absolutely positioned element with no href attribute or setting focus to a hidden input element first, but the cursor will probably take precedence and show the url anyway.  A better way to do this is to overlay your anchor tag with a div - like a lightbox when the page loads - or if you're using JS - consider removing the anchor link and using divs with click event capture if that works in your situation.  Sounds like a kiosk question I looked at here the other day.

Comment: If I understood that correctly you want to trigger an event first time the user moves the mouse after the page is loaded? Is that right? If so, you can monitor the mouse position, as soon as it changes, the user moved the mouse. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MyStream, yes it is the same person you were trying to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457598/how-to-set-cursor-off-screen but I'm stuck on this one, cos asking the vendor to remove the status bar was not an option. I couldn't remove all the a tag either due to some button effect there. So I'm asking for help again to deal with the status bar situation. Can you give me more details on the light box thing, how can I target it? Thanks.

Comment: @Deabtoni, yes what I'm trying to achieve is to avoid customers to see the status bar address when the page is just loaded (because it is an a tag page with the mouse pointer on), it's ok if people click on the page to see the address bar. That's why this move the cursor off the screen came to my mind, but now i know it is not possible. Which method do you reckon I can make the status bar disappear? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @SamIAm - do you want help off stackoverflow - sounds more like you need directed help than a technical issue - give me a shout on my site if you want help (we've worked with kiosk programmers and suppliers).

Comment: Hi @MyStream, thanks for the offer. I'd love some help from some other professionals like you if this is my business, but I think it's gonna be hard to convince my boss at this stage. However I'll keep you in mind in the further for sure. Thank you!

Comment: @MyStream, I just saw this comment, it's so very kind of you. I'll keep that in mind, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the focus to a specific input element. That way you can control what happens when the user next types some text. Google for "setfocus javascript"

But you can't control the mouse. The user controls the mouse.

Comment: sorry I didn't make myself clear. the reason I want to move the mouse pointer off screen is because the page I'm creating is an a tag page, so people click anywhere next page will show. I don't want people to see the status bar address when they open the page until they move the mouse and interact with the page. Can focus do that? Or any other ways? Thanks.