# control mouse location on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a webpage that display a slider (almost all screen) and that slider will stop when the mouse pointer is over it. I want the mouse pointer display on the top of page (where it is not over the div)

I know javascript cannot control mouse but I want to the mouse pointer is moved (displayed) outside a div after pageload.

Is there any way to do that or any solution?
Thank you

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488626/how-to-set-the-cursor-position-on-the-screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move the mouse pointer to a specific position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752501/move-the-mouse-pointer-to-a-specific-position)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to not have the script enabled that stops the slider when the page load. Then:

- detect the mouse location on page load
- if it happens to outside the slider, enable the slider-stopping script
- if it happens to be over the slider, register a script that will enable the slider stopping script once the mouse is moved outside the slider